# Java - Como creo un método para imprimir una imagen en distintos JLabels?

Tags: java, jlabel

Estaba haciendo una tarea acerca de las expresiones regulares, en donde se introduce un valor según la casilla, cada casilla tiene un JLabel donde se imprime una imagen y este se valida cuando el correspondiente boton es orpimido, si es valido se imprime un icono con una palomita, si no es validado se imprime un icono con un tache, el problema es que seria mucho codigo imprimir la imagen para cada JLabel, y estuve intentando englobar todos en dos metodos sin embargo el problema es que no consigo que el metodo le imprima a todos distintos JLabels
[![Imagen de como se ven los campos en el JFrame]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJzEL.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJzEL.png)

Los metodos que intente hacer son:

```
//Metodo que imprime la imagen de la palomita
    public void IMGC(){ 
    obj1= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Accep.png"));
    Icono= new ImageIcon (obj1.getImage().getScaledInstance(JLIMG1.getWidth(),JLIMG1.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)); 
    JLIMG1.setIcon(Icono);    
    }
    
    //Metodo que imprune la imagen del tache
    public void IMGD(){
    obj1= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Cancel.png"));
    Icono= new ImageIcon (obj1.getImage().getScaledInstance(JLIMG1.getWidth(),JLIMG1.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)); 
    JLIMG1.setIcon(Icono);    
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué a *"a todos distintos JLabels"* ?, si sólo presionas un botón a la vez. Hay varias soluciones, la clave esta en cómo (cuándo y dónde) estableces la relación entre cierto botón con su correspondiente JLabel.